# Password field is not arriving to php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery

So i am having an issue debugging where the issue is. Could be Jquery or PHP issue. I have done quite a bit of alert testing and i believe the issue lies in the if statement of ajax, eg i am posting pass if the field is not disabled when posting. Because when doing a echo $_POST['pass'] and alert(data), i get nothing. So i believe the php is working fine please tell me where the issue lies and if you know also the remedy to this situation. Thanks Guys.

Ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', '#editaccsount', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

myData = {
        contactname: $('input[name=contactname]').val(),
        business: $('input[name=business]').val(),
        email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
        code: $('input[name=code]').val(),
        phone: $('input[name=phone]').val(),
        priceband: $('input[name=priceband]').val(),
        address: $('input[name=address]').val(),
        active: $('input[name=active]').val(),
        mon: $('input[name=mon]').val(),
        tue: $('input[name=tue]').val(),
        wed: $('input[name=wed]').val(),
        thu: $('input[name=thu]').val(),
        fri: $('input[name=fri]').val(),
        sat: $('input[name=sat]').val(),
        sund: $('input[name=sund]').val(),
        adminname: $('input[name=adminname]').val(),
        accountid: $('input[name=accountid]').val(),
        isadmin: $('input[name=isadmin]').val(),
};

var isDisabled = $('input[name=pass]').prop('disabled');

if (isDisabled == false) {
        myData.pass = $('input[name=pass]').val();
}
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/editaccount.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: myData,
    success: function(data) {

        if ($('input[name=isadmin]').val() == 1) {
            $('input[name=accountsearch]').val($('input[name=email]').val());
            $('input[name=accountsearch]').submit();
        } else {
                $('input[name=accountsearch]').val($('input[name=business]').val());
            $('input[name=accountsearch]').submit();
        }

        alert(data);
    }
});
});
```

This is my PHP that does all the updating based on conditions:

```
<?php

require '../../core/init.php';

$auth = new Auth();


$accid = $_POST['accountid'];

echo $accid, '<br/>';
echo 'Password is: ', $_POST['pass'], '<br/>';
echo 'Is Admin: ', $_POST['isadmin'];

if (!empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    echo 'Pass Detected';
    echo 'Password: ', $_POST['pass'], "<br/>";

    $salt = $auth->randomString();
    $newpass = $salt . $_POST['pass'];
    $newpass = $auth->hashData($newpass);


    if ($_POST['isadmin'] == 0) {

        $customer = DBPDO::getInstance()->update('customer', $accid, array(
                'businessName'      =>  $_POST['business'],
                'contactName'       =>  $_POST['contactname'],
                'email'             =>  $_POST['email'],
                'code'              =>  $_POST['code'],
                'phone'             =>  $_POST['phone'],
                'priceBand'         =>  $_POST['priceband'],
                'deliveryAddress'   =>  $_POST['address'],
                'is_active'         =>  $_POST['active'],
                'mon'               =>  $_POST['mon'],
                'tue'               =>  $_POST['tue'],
                'wed'               =>  $_POST['wed'],
                'thu'               =>  $_POST['thu'],
                'fri'               =>  $_POST['fri'],
                'sat'               =>  $_POST['sat'],
                'sun'               =>  $_POST['sund'],
                'password'          =>  $newpass,
                'user_salt'         =>  $salt
            ));
    } elseif ($_POST['isadmin'] == 1) {

        $admin = DBPDO::getInstance()->update('admin', $accid, array(
                'adminName'         =>  $_POST['adminname'],
                'email'             =>  $_POST['email'],
                'phone'             =>  $_POST['phone'],
                'password'          =>  $newpass,
                'user_salt'         =>  $salt
            ));
    }


} elseif (empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    echo 'Pass NOT detected';

    if ($_POST['isadmin'] == 0) {

        $customer = DBPDO::getInstance()->update('customer', $accid, array(
                'businessName'      =>  $_POST['business'],
                'contactName'       =>  $_POST['contactname'],
                'email'             =>  $_POST['email'],
                'code'              =>  $_POST['code'],
                'phone'             =>  $_POST['phone'],
                'priceBand'         =>  $_POST['priceband'],
                'deliveryAddress'   =>  $_POST['address'],
                'mon'               =>  $_POST['mon'],
                'tue'               =>  $_POST['tue'],
                'wed'               =>  $_POST['wed'],
                'thu'               =>  $_POST['thu'],
                'fri'               =>  $_POST['fri'],
                'sat'               =>  $_POST['sat'],
                'sun'               =>  $_POST['sund']
            ));
    } elseif ($_POST['isadmin'] == 1) {

        $admin = DBPDO::getInstance()->update('admin', $accid, array(
                'adminName'         =>  $_POST['adminname'],
                'email'             =>  $_POST['email'],
                'phone'             =>  $_POST['phone']
            ));
    }

}
```

What gets outputted as HTML:

```
<?php

require '../../core/init.php';
$data['result_1'] = '';
$searchquery = $_POST['accountsearch'];

if ($_POST['accounttype'] == 'Users') {

$customer = DBPDO::getInstance()->get('customer', array(
                array('businessName', '=', "'$searchquery'" )
            ));

foreach ($customer->results() as $row)
{
    $data['result_1'] .= '

    <div class="row row-centered">
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" name="editbtn" value="Edit Account">
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger remove-btn" type="button" name="removebtn" value="Remove Account" uid="'.$row->id.'">
    </div><br/>
        <form id="editaccount" action="php/editaccount.php" method="POST">
            <h3>General Details</h3>
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contactname">Customer Name</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="contactname" class="form-control" value="'.$row->contactName.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="business">Business</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="business" class="form-control" value="'.$row->businessName.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="email" disabled="disabled" name="email" class="form-control" value="'.$row->email.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="code">Code</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="code" class="form-control" value="'.$row->code.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="phone" class="form-control" value="'.$row->phone.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="priceband">Price Band</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="priceband" class="form-control" value="'.$row->priceBand.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address">Delivery Address</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="address" class="form-control" value="'.$row->deliveryAddress.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pass">Active</label>               
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="test" disabled="disabled" name="active" class="form-control" value="'.$row->is_active.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pass">Password</label>               
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="password" disabled="disabled" name="userpass" class="form-control" value="'.$row->password.'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input id="editpasswordbtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" value="Edit Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrning" style="color:red;display:none;">
                <b>Warning: </b> If you do NOT want to edit Password please click Cancel!<br/><br/>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Cancel Password Change">
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
            <h3>Standing Order Details</h3>
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="mon">Monday</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="mon" class="form-control" value="'.$row->mon.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tue">Tuesday</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="tue" class="form-control" value="'.$row->tue.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="wed">Wednesday</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="wed" class="form-control" value="'.$row->wed.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="thu">Thursday</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="thu" class="form-control" value="'.$row->thu.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fri">Friday</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="fri" class="form-control" value="'.$row->fri.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sat">Saturday</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="sat" class="form-control" value="'.$row->sat.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sund">Sunday</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="sund" class="form-control" value="'.$row->sun.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-centered">
                    <input type="hidden" name="accountid" value="'.$row->id.'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="isadmin" value="0">
                    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-rj" disabled="disabled" type="submit" name="editbtn" value="Send to Database">
            </div>  
        </form>
    ';
}   
} elseif ($_POST['accounttype'] == 'Admins') {
$customer = DBPDO::getInstance()->get('admin', array(
                array('email', '=', "'$searchquery'" )
            ));

foreach ($customer->results() as $row)
{
    $data['result_1'] .= '
        <div class="row row-centered">
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button"  name="editbtn" value="Edit Account">
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger remove-btn adminremove-btn"  type="button" name="adminremovebtn" value="Remove Account" uid="'.$row->id.'">
        </div><br/>
        <form id="editaccount" action="php/editaccount.php" method="POST">
            <h3>General Details</h3>
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contactname">Admin Name</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="adminname" class="form-control" value="'.$row->adminName.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contactname">Email</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="email" class="form-control" value="'.$row->email.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="business">Phone</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="phone" class="form-control" value="'.$row->phone.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-centered" style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>                
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="hidden" name="isadmin" value="1">
                            <input type="password" disabled="disabled" name="pass" class="form-control" value="'.$row->password.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <input type="hidden" name="accountid" value="'.$row- >id.'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="isadmin" value="1">
                    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-rj" disabled="disabled" type="submit" name="editbtn" value="Send to Database">
                </div>  
            </div>
        </form>
    ';
}   
}


echo json_encode($data);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked that your isDisabled is set correctly and its getting into the if(isDisabled) statement?

Comment: Yes i have tried that using console, And it picks it up in console but its not sending to the php. So i am a little confused .

Comment: Does everything else get sent? I'm used to serializing the data before sending it usually. You can do $('myForm').serialize() and it will serialize the form for you as well, instead of doing all those .val's.

Comment: I havent ever tried serialize() not sure how it works, but yes the other data in the form does update using ajax. After trying various things, i still think its something to do with the ajax. I have another field on the page with the same name=pass. Would changing the query a little to select name=pass from nearest form would work?

Comment: Yes, if you have 2 then $('input[name=pass]') will return a collection like: ['<input>', '<input>'], so doing .val on that will not give you the result you want. You need to either take the one you want out of that collection or select more specifically. Take the form it is in and do $('form').find('input[name=pass]')

Comment: Are we able to open a chat somehow so i can show you my setup, and perhaps you might be able to see the issue.

Comment: Can you add the html to please?

Comment: HTML is long i am unsure if i am allowed to add alot of code here.

Comment: Can you post at least the part where the input pass is?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the property of disabled with:

```
var isDisabled = $('input[name=pass]').prop('disabled');
```

If I recall this will return a string empty or `disabled` as a way to use this would be:

```
$('input[name=pass]').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

If you're looking for a `true/false` maybe try with:

```
var isDisabled = $('input[name=pass]').is(':disabled');
```

and it will return true or false.

Comment: I will post my php up as well just in case, i tried this method but i still get no pass in php or field update in table.

Comment: I think it should work if you replace var isDisabled = $('input[name=pass]').prop('disabled'); with  var isDisabled = $('input[name=pass]').is(':disabled'); in your code as Fabrizio Mazzoni suggested.